# Tomcat error 500 on page load

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I am getting the following error on Tomcat.
The code is given below

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher
    DBChart.doGet(DBChart.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ezmorph.Morpher
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    DBChart.doGet(DBChart.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Below is my Java file

```
//imported all the required packages here   
class DBChart extends HttpServlet
{

    Connection c = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = null;
    JSONObject obj = null;
    JSONObject resobj = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = null;
    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName = EMPLOYEE";
    String user = "username";
    String password = "mypassword";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            List<JSONObject> Details = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
            query = " select DeptName, NumberOfEmployess from Departments";
            pst = c.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String dept = rs.getString(1);
                int empnumber = rs.getInt(2);
                obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("DepartmentName", dept);
                obj.put("EmployeesinNumbers", empnumber);
                Details.add(obj);
            }
            resobj.put("RelativeDetails", Details);
            out.write(resobj.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

I made sure that I have mentioned the correct name in XMl file and using the url as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/DBCHART/db
```

Comment: Is there another exception following after the exception you posted (If yes, post it too). And another advice: you should change your password now, after you posted it in public.

Comment: @Joachim Rohde: Sure, Thanks , i will just change. yes,There is an error following it.I have updated it above in the post.PLease have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class needs to be public:

> public class DBChart extends HttpServlet

Comment: It resolved the earlier error but came up with another.I have updated it in the question.Please let me know if I need to start another thread for it.Thank you

Comment: For another problem you should usually start another thread. But the error message "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ezmorph.Morpher" is quite clear. You are missing a class (or jar-file).